# How to Scan sdcard images through code

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-mediascanner

i want to scan the sdcard images to display images in my application.
When i taken the picture from camera i am able to save the images in sdcard from the application, but not able to show them.
But when i copy the image manually in the phone sdcard media scanning is running and i am able to show the images.
My question is, is there any way to median scan the sdcard through coding?

Comment: First link on google: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/cf41cc88b6eb4393?pli=1

Comment: i have already tried this, not working for me...

Comment: i think it would be better if you could post some of your codes. I think @Jokahero suggestion should work.

Comment: By the way, do you need to scan all the files in the sd card or just the file that you've added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me to scan the sdcard it is working in my mobile:

```
  sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+
                     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) may help you with what you're trying to do.

By calling [scanFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) you can ask to the scanner to check your newly created file.

Hope it helps.

Jokahero